# Keras LSTM: ValueError : Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1440, 60, 1)

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I need Help with my Keras nn Architecture for price prediction.

**EDIT**

This is how i scale and order my data:

history is a list of prices in the lookback time, in my example 60 * 24 for the whole day.

```
                for i in range(1, len(history), self.timesteps): 
                    prices_x.append(list(history[i:i + self.timesteps]))
                for i in range(0, len(history) - 1, self.timesteps): 
                    prices_y.append(list(history[i:i + self.timesteps]))

                #First Feed the lookback History  
                x_data = np.array(prices_x)
                y_data = np.array(prices_y)

                x_data = self.scaler.fit_transform(x_data)
                y_data = self.scaler.fit_transform(y_data)
                # reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
                x_data = np.reshape(x_data, (x_data.shape[0], x_data.shape[1], 1))
                y_data = np.reshape(y_data, (y_data.shape[0], y_data.shape[1], 1))
```

This is my lstm so far (simplified):

```
    self._opt_cells = 1
    self.model = Sequential()

    self.model.add(LSTM(units = self._opt_cells, return_sequences = False, input_shape = (self.input_cells, 1)))

    self.model.add(Dense(1)) #, activation='linear'))

    adam = Adam(clipnorm=1.)

    self.model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

My Train Shape is something like (1440, 60, 1) (num_features, timesteps, feature)

Then the following Error is raising:

ValueError : Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1440, 60, 1) ValueError : Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1440, 60, 1)

Why does the LSTM returns a sequence with return_sequences set to false?
What am i doing wrong?!

Comment: have you tried this
`self.model.add(Flatten())`
`self.model.add(Dense())`
actually flatten layer automatically convert multi dimension data to 1 dimension data, so that data can be accepted by next dense layer

Comment: yes i also tried the Flatten Layer without any paramters. And the Dense need at least one parameter for the units. Resulting is always the same...

Comment: What are your labels ? Your are expecting an output shape that is the same as your input shape ? Here the error says that the Dense expect a label of shape (batch, output_cells), but you are feeding a label array of shape (batch, 60, 1)

Comment: But why? my Train data is in Shape (1440, 60, 1) when i feed it to the lstm with return_sequences to false, i expecting an output shape of (1440, 1). Why does my LSTM layer return the whole sequence?